# Validate form but if no errors do not show the fields

Tags: php, forms, validation

I seem to be struggling with some code recently. It has a select form which is validated on submit. If there is an error, it reports that there is an error and also shows the form again below for the user to correct it. However, if there are no errors and everything is successful, it still shows the form below it. I do not want it to do display the form when there are no errors, how is this possible with the way I have it set up?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
if ($row2[matches] == 3)
    {
    if ($_POST["matches"] == 1 & $_POST["matches2"] == 1) $error["matches"] = "<span class='error'><span class='errorbox'><img src='images/other/error2.png' style='vertical-align:middle' /></span>ERROR: You are attempting to report an invalid score!</span>";
    if ($_POST["matches"] + $_POST["matches2"] < 2) $error["matches"] = "<span class='error'><span class='errorbox'><img src='images/other/error2.png' style='vertical-align:middle' /></span>ERROR: You are attempting to report an invalid score!</span>";
    if ($_POST["matches"] + $_POST["matches2"] == 4) $error["matches"] = "<span class='error'><span class='errorbox'><img src='images/other/error2.png' style='vertical-align:middle' /></span>ERROR: You cannot have 4 matches!</span>";
    }

if ($row2[matches] == 1)
    {
    if ($_POST["matches"] + $_POST["matches2"] < 1) $error["matches"] = "<span class='error'><span class='errorbox'><img src='images/other/error2.png' style='vertical-align:middle' /></span>ERROR: You are attempting to report an invalid score!</span>";
    if ($_POST["matches"] + $_POST["matches2"] == 2) $error["matches"] = "<span class='error'><span class='errorbox'><img src='images/other/error2.png' style='vertical-align:middle' /></span>ERROR: You are attempting to report an invalid score!</span>";
    }

if ($error["matches"] == '')
    {
    echo "test";
    }


}
?>

 <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>?&id=<?php
echo "$id"; ?>">
  <select name="matches">
  <?php

 if ($row2[matches] == 1)
   {
   echo "<option value='0'>0</option>";
   echo "<option value='1'>1</option>";
   }
 elseif ($row2[matches] == 3)
   {
   echo "<option value='0'>0</option>";
   echo "<option value='1'>1</option>";
   echo "<option value='2'>2</option>";
   }

?>
</select>
<select name="matches2">
<?php

if ($row2[matches] == 1)
{
echo "<option value='0'>0</option>";
echo "<option value='1'>1</option>";
}
elseif ($row2[matches] == 3)
{
echo "<option value='0'>0</option>";
echo "<option value='1'>1</option>";
echo "<option value='2'>2</option>";
}

?>
</select>
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" class="md-trigger blue-texture postbit-button-big md-pointer" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Put the entire form inside an `if`: `if (!empty($error["matches"])) { ... }`

Comment: That does not work because it does not matter if the form is empty or not, it matters completely upon the $error[matches]. Also, when setting that if statement only on the form, the form will only be visible if a submit has been made to show an error, rather than just starting on the page.

Comment: Add a variable `$validated` initially set it to false. If no errors are found set it to `true`. Put your form in an `if (! $validated)` condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php
    $validated = false;
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    if ($row2[matches] == 3)
        {
        if ($_POST["matches"] == 1 & $_POST["matches2"] == 1) $error["matches"] = "<span class='error'><span class='errorbox'><img src='images/other/error2.png' style='vertical-align:middle' /></span>ERROR: You are attempting to report an invalid score!</span>";
        if ($_POST["matches"] + $_POST["matches2"] < 2) $error["matches"] = "<span class='error'><span class='errorbox'><img src='images/other/error2.png' style='vertical-align:middle' /></span>ERROR: You are attempting to report an invalid score!</span>";
        if ($_POST["matches"] + $_POST["matches2"] == 4) $error["matches"] = "<span class='error'><span class='errorbox'><img src='images/other/error2.png' style='vertical-align:middle' /></span>ERROR: You cannot have 4 matches!</span>";
        }

    if ($row2[matches] == 1)
        {
        if ($_POST["matches"] + $_POST["matches2"] < 1) $error["matches"] = "<span class='error'><span class='errorbox'><img src='images/other/error2.png' style='vertical-align:middle' /></span>ERROR: You are attempting to report an invalid score!</span>";
        if ($_POST["matches"] + $_POST["matches2"] == 2) $error["matches"] = "<span class='error'><span class='errorbox'><img src='images/other/error2.png' style='vertical-align:middle' /></span>ERROR: You are attempting to report an invalid score!</span>";
        }

    if ($error["matches"] == '')
        {
        $validated = true;
        }


    }
    ?>
    if (! $validated) {
     <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>?&id=<?php
    echo "$id"; ?>">
      <select name="matches">
      <?php

     if ($row2[matches] == 1)
       {
       echo "<option value='0'>0</option>";
       echo "<option value='1'>1</option>";
       }
     elseif ($row2[matches] == 3)
       {
       echo "<option value='0'>0</option>";
       echo "<option value='1'>1</option>";
       echo "<option value='2'>2</option>";
       }

    ?>
    </select>
    <select name="matches2">
    <?php

    if ($row2[matches] == 1)
    {
    echo "<option value='0'>0</option>";
    echo "<option value='1'>1</option>";
    }
    elseif ($row2[matches] == 3)
    {
    echo "<option value='0'>0</option>";
    echo "<option value='1'>1</option>";
    echo "<option value='2'>2</option>";
    }

    ?>
    </select>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" class="md-trigger blue-texture postbit-button-big md-pointer" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're storing your errors within `$error["matches"]` from what I can see, so a simple `if()` should suffice.

```
if (empty($error['matches']) == FALSE) {
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>?&id=<?php echo "$id"; ?>">
        <select name="matches">
            <?php
            if ($row2[matches] == 1) {
                echo "<option value='0'>0</option>";
                echo "<option value='1'>1</option>";
            } elseif ($row2[matches] == 3) {
                echo "<option value='0'>0</option>";
                echo "<option value='1'>1</option>";
                echo "<option value='2'>2</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <select name="matches2">
            <?php
            if ($row2[matches] == 1) {
                echo "<option value='0'>0</option>";
                echo "<option value='1'>1</option>";
            } elseif ($row2[matches] == 3) {
                echo "<option value='0'>0</option>";
                echo "<option value='1'>1</option>";
                echo "<option value='2'>2</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" class="md-trigger blue-texture postbit-button-big md-pointer" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
<?php
   }
 ?>
```

And for the sake of good practice, let's instantiate `$error` on line 1.

```
$error = array("matches" => array());
```